# Excel: Summing numerical values using VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vlookup

The first spreadsheet "2017 Annual" has a list of courses by course number. On the second sheet I have a list of "pending invoices" that have their corresponding course number connected to it. I would like to find all invoices that have the same course number, add their values together if they have the same course number and put that on the first spreadsheet under "pending money".

My first inclination was to use a vlookup: Something like this =SUM(VLOOKUP($E$2:$E$83,'pending invoices'!$A$2:$L$13,6,FALSE)). Yet it just returns N/A. I am using ctrl shift enter.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMIF`, without seeing your data I would assume something like

```
=SUMIF('pending invoices'!$A$2:$A$13, $E2, $L$2:$L$13)
```

Where

```
=SUMIF(range, criteria, sum-range)
```